# Get,Set Operation on Arrays

Tags: testcomplete

How to use Get Set properties on arrays in c# scripting.In order to set particular index and to get the value what is the procedure should be followed?
I am using Test complete software and c#scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TestComplete's C#Script is actually [JScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hbxc2t98%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) with square bracket notation instead of dot notation. You can manipulate arrays in C#Script in the same way as in JScript (or JavaScript, which is similar):

```js
// Define an array using an array literal
var names = ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"];
Log.Message(names[0]); // "Alice"

// Create and populate an array using a loop
var numbers = new Array(); // or: var numbers = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  numbers[i] = i;
}
Log.Message(numbers.join()); // "0,1,2,3,4"
```